# Inserting to Matrix of Unknown Dimensionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, multidimensional-array, reference

I am having trouble writing a setter-function for a Matrix class that is supposed to handle multidimensional matrices for my implementation of a dynamic programming algorithm.

The matrix is stored using a nested list. Since the dimensionality is not known the idea behind the code is to use a coordinate (a list of indices) and iteratively step into the matrix upon reading an index from the coordinate.

```
def setField(self, coordinate, value):
    coordinate = coordinate[::-1] # reverse the coordinate so .pop() can be used 
    field = self.matrix
    while len(coordinate) > 1:
        field = field[coordinate.pop()]

    field[coordinate[0]] = value
```

Using the Code:

```
>>> m = Matrix([3,3,3]) # initialize Matrix of size 3 in all dimensions
>>> m.tolist() # list representation
[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
>>> m.setField([1,1,1], 42) # at position [1,1,1] insert 42
>>> m.tolist()
[[[0, 0, 42], [0, 0, 42], [0, 0, 42]], [[0, 0, 42], [0, 0, 42], [0, 0, 42]], [[0, 0, 42], [0, 0, 42], [0, 0, 42]]]
```

Now the trouble is, that the 'stepping into the matrix' part is done with a reference to the matrix. For reasons I don't understand, the change is not just happening in one field (where the matrix is supposed to be changed to the given value), but occurs in every sublist of the matrix representation.

What confuses me even more, is that the following code works just fine in a Python shell:

```
>>> m = [[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> field = m
>>> field = field[0]
>>> field[1] = 1
>>> m
[[0, 1], [0, 0]]
```

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Why is Python behaving that way?

---

**Edit / Explanation**

As pointed out as an Answer, all sublists in the matrix actually are the same.

```
>>> m = Matrix([2,2])
>>> id(m.matrix[0]) == id(m.matrix[1])
True
```

To avoid this behaviour, copies have to be used.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  Also, what does *not only the one desired field in the matrix is changed* mean?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using numpy? No reason to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @user3080953 I will be using the class to represent scoring matrices and performance is not an issue. There are however a couple of different initializations it needs to cover, so I thought it best to wrap them up in a class.

Comment: @wallyk The issue was, that a change to one of the sublists in the matrix representation occured in all sublists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because sub-arrays of your matrix are actually the same thing in memory, so modifying one changes them all.

This is what you're doing:

```
>>> a = [0, 0]
>>> m = [a, a]
>>> m
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> m[0][1] = 42
>>> m
[[0, 42], [0, 42]]
>>> id(m[0]) == id(m[1]) # same object in memory
True
```

This is what you want to do:

```
>>> a = [0,0]
>>> m = [a.copy(), a.copy()]
>>> m[0][1] = 42
>>> m
[[0, 42], [0, 0]]
>>> id(m[0]) == id(m[1]) # different objects in memory
False
```

That being said, it's a lot easier to do in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.zeros((2, 2))
>>> m[0,1] = 42
>>> m
array([[  0.,  42.],
       [  0.,   0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was guessing that it was something like this, but I got really confused when it worked in the shell.